# grep lines before with pattern "match and not match"

Tags: awk, grep

Having the following content in the file test.txt:

```
line 1  
foo bar  
line 2  
foo
```

I need to **return the line before the line that contains foo but does not contain bar**

In the example, the result must be:

```
line 2  
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v bar fyle.txt | grep -B 1 foo
```

gets one line before foo but not with bar

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` it's very easy to combine regular expression matches with logical operators:

```
$ awk '/foo/ && !/bar/{printf "%s\n%s\n",last,$0}{last=$0}' file
line 2  
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "negative lookahead" expression (requires enabling perl regular expressions using the grep's command line parameter `-P`)

```
grep -P -B1 '(foo)(?!.*bar.*)' data.txt
```

Comment: You'd also want a look behind and variable length look arounds aren't supported widely as they are very expensive.